# How to display exactly 6 previous month's by their name from the current date in a select drop down list?

Tags: html, angularjs

The project i am working on needs to display 6 previous months by name in a select drop down list which will then be sent to service units .
Is there a way to do it using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

var today = new Date();
var d;
var month;

for(var i = 6; i > 0; i -= 1) {
  d = new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth() - i, 1);
  month = monthNames[d.getMonth()];
  console.log(month);
}
```

Comment: thanks syed,suits well 4 my project!

Comment: Then please click on Tick as correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```js
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = [];
    var current = moment().month();
    for(var i = 6; i > 0; i--)
      $scope.data.push(moment.months(current - i));
    $scope.selected = $scope.data[0]    
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="ctrl">
    <select ng-options="item for item in data" ng-model="selected"></select>
    {{selected}}
</div>
```

Comment: thanks,this helped!